# WPF chart "No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value"

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

Can you please help with WPF chart (chartingToolkit:Chart). 
I am trying to bind the chart to a `List<Type>` but I am getting an error that says "No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value".

My Xaml code:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="graphFinancialPerformance" Title="Financial   Performance" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300">

<chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="PerPortionPercentage" IndependentValuePath="Month" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FinancialPerformanceGraph}" IsSelectionEnabled="True">
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

In my ViewModel:

The List FinancialPerformanceGraph is getting populated with data from the database but it seems like the Chart doesn't know how to deal with the  which is FinancialPerformance.

The `PerMonthPercentage` and `Month` are defined in the `FinancialPerformance` class as int and string properties.

I have checked and the FinancialPerformanceGraph is getting data from the database.

I am using MVVM.

I will appropriate any help. Thank you guys.

Comment: Post your `ViewModel` and `Model` classes.

Comment: Is it `PerMonthPercentage` or `PerPortionPercentage` ?